# Balance of the account doesn't change after executing payable method

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, testrpc, ethereumjs

I have a problem when invoking a payable method. The funds are being transferred to a contract (the balance of the contract changes). However, the balance of the account who is sending a transaction is still the same. I am using solidity 0.4.18 and testrpc. Here is the code that I am using:

`event NewHighestBid(address bidder, uint amount, bytes32 auctionName, bool test);
function bid(bytes32 _auctionName) payable {
NewHighestBid(msg.sender, msg.value, _auctionName, true);
}`

I followed the documentation, but the the balance of the account is not changing for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a higher amount. Because if you send 1 wei, it will be hard to debug because when it paid for gas, it will be higher than 1 wei. By the way, is the account of the sender not changing at all? Because it must be paying for gas.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured that out but still thank you!